# Trying to print with specific format from DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

new to Python and trying to print from a data frame

```
    customers = {'NAME': ['Breadpot', 'Hoviz', 'Hovis', 'Grenns', 'Magnolia', 'Dozen', 'Sun'],
      'CITY': ['Sydney', 'Manchester', 'London', 'London', 'Chicago', 'San Francisco', 'San Francisco'],
      'COUNTRY': ['Australia', 'UK', 'UK', 'UK', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA'],
      'CPERSON': ['Sam.Keng@info.com', 'harry.ham@hoviz.com', 'hamlet.host@hoviz.com', 'grenns@grenns.com', 'man@info.com', 'dozen@dozen.com', 'sunny@sun.com'],
      'EMPLCNT': [250, 150, 1500, 200, 1024, 1000, 2000],
      'CONTRCNT': [48, 7, 12800, 12800, 25600, 5, 2],
      'CONTRCOST': [1024.00, 900.00, 10510.50, 128.30, 512000.00, 1000.20, 10000.01]
      }

df = pd.DataFrame(customers, columns=['CITY', 'COUNTRY', 'CPERSON', 'EMPLCNT', 'CONTRCNT', 'EMPLCNT', 'CONTRCOST'])

new_df = df.loc[df['CONTRCNT'].idxmax()]
print('City with the largest number of signed contracts:')
print(new_df['CITY'],'(', new_df['CONTRCNT'], 'contracts)')
```

Trying to get code to return "City with largest number of contracts:" "city" ("number of contracts")

but instead keep getting this:

```
City with the largest number of signed contracts:
4    Chicago
4    Chicago
Name: CITY, dtype: object (    CONTRCNT  CONTRCNT
4     25600     25600
4     25600     25600 contracts)
```

Comment: what you expecting to print?

Comment: based on the dataframe, should print "City with the largest number of signed contracts: Chicago (25600 contracts)"

Comment: The df contains the same columns repeating,`'EMPLCNT', 'CONTRCNT', 'EMPLCNT', 'CONTRCNT'`. Remove the duplicated columns, your code works fine

Comment: ah didn't see that, thank you. when running it now it returns correctly, but have an extra space in ( 25600 contracts), how would I fix that?

Comment: You can use `+` instead of `,` and convert the number to type str, like this`print(new_df['CITY'] + ' (' + str(new_df['CONTRCNT']) + 'contracts)')`

Comment: This worked! thanks a bunch Rajesh!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
customers = {'NAME': ['Breadpot', 'Hoviz', 'Hovis', 'Grenns', 'Magnolia', 'Dozen', 'Sun'],
      'CITY': ['Sydney', 'Manchester', 'London', 'London', 'Chicago', 'San Francisco', 'San Francisco'],
      'COUNTRY': ['Australia', 'UK', 'UK', 'UK', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA'],
      'CPERSON': ['Sam.Keng@info.com', 'harry.ham@hoviz.com', 'hamlet.host@hoviz.com', 'grenns@grenns.com', 'man@info.com', 'dozen@dozen.com', 'sunny@sun.com'],
      'EMPLCNT': [250, 150, 1500, 200, 1024, 1000, 2000],
      'CONTRCNT': [48, 7, 12800, 12800, 25600, 5, 2],
      'CONTRCOST': [1024.00, 900.00, 10510.50, 128.30, 512000.00, 1000.20, 10000.01]
      }

df = pd.DataFrame(customers, columns=['CITY', 'COUNTRY', 'CPERSON', 'EMPLCNT', 'CONTRCNT', 'CONTRCOST'])
new_df = df.groupby('CITY').sum().sort_values(by='CONTRCNT', ascending = False)
print('City with the largest number of signed contracts:')
print(new_df.index.values[0],'(', new_df.iloc[0][1], 'contracts)')
```